# Пример getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

Всем привет создал небольшой код для пробы

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").value="new text"
```

при этом в строке ничего не меняется, хотя если использовать id

```
document.getElementById("in").value="new text"
```

то всё получается, почему так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Функция `getElementsByTagName` возвращает массив элементов. Для обращения к определенному элементу нужно указать индекс:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="new text";
```

Answer (score 5):

> The getElement**s**ByTagName() method *returns a NodeList of all elements* with a specified name.

> Метод getElement**s**ByTagName() *возвращает список NodeList из всех элементов* с указанным именем.

Comment: опередили)

Comment: @Павел Азанов, а вы разжевали зато :)